# Connect to Different Database in October CMS

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, content-management-system, octobercms

### Connecting to Different Database in October CMS

Hello,

I have two databases first one was created by OctoberCMS during installation process and the other one which i had already. how do i connect to that other database, i tried using builder plug-in but i am confused how to do it.

I want to connect to the other database and fetch information from one table and display on my home page.

Please help me with this. I am newbie to this CMS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your `config/database.php` you will have something like this (assuming MySQL):

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'port'      => 3306,
        'database'  => 'database_name',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ],
```

Just add another one after it, changing the name to something else (`mysql-legacy` in my example below) and the relevant connection details:

```
    'mysql-legacy' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'port'      => 3306,
        'database'  => 'database_name',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ],
```

After that, you can `use DB;` in your model or controller and then do things like this:

```
$query = DB::connection('mysql-legacy')->select('SELECT * FROM tablename');
```